# Retrieved unmasking value from inputmask masking value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask

I use input inputmask on my form input, this is code that make mask on my form

```
$('input[name="jumlah"]').inputmask("decimal", {
        groupSeparator: ".",
        autoGroup: true
});
```

then i need to get the value from the input with this way

```
var checkVal = $('input[name="jumlah"]').val();
```

i keep get mask value,

Ex:
on the input field when input number i can see 33.333 value on my field. then i need retrieved only 33333

how to get unmask value from input?

Answer (score 3):

InputMask has a property that might help you: 'removeMaskOnSubmit'

Just set it as `true` and you should be good.

Something like this:

```
Inputmask.extendDefaults({
  'removeMaskOnSubmit': true
});
```

[found here (external link)](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)